# How to modify the value of class b in a class a without declaring an object of the class?

Tags: c++, class

I want to try to access the value in class b, and modify it, or use it, what should I do?

```
#include <iostream>

class a
{
    public:
        class b
        {
            public:
                int c;
        };
};

int main(void)
{
    a::b.c = 10;
    //or
    a new_a;
    new_a.b.c = 10;
    new_a::b.c = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `a` contains just the definition of `b`, not an instance of it.

You would have to do something like this to access `b`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class a
{
    public:
        class b
        {
            public:
                int c;
        };
};

int main(void)
{
    a::b new_b;
    new_b.c = 10;
}
```

Or you might want to do this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class a
{
    public:
        class b
        {
            public:
                int c;
        };
    b b_in_a;
};

int main(void)
{
    a new_a;
    new_a.b_in_a.c = 10;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if i want to define the function inside b what should i do? is int new_a.b_in_a::c(void)?

Comment: @ZhenzheGao that's a different question. Try googling "C++ nested classes"

Comment: Will this problem be hard to solve?